# Did the OCaml compiler change drastically since RWO?

Tags: ocaml

Example from Real World OCaml Page 60

```
List.map ~f:((+) 3) [4;5;6;];;
Error: The function applied to this argument has type 'a list -> 'b list
This argument cannot be applied with label ~f
```

Same example from the HTML hosted version of RWO

```
List.map ~f:((+) 3) [4;5;6];;
- : int list = [7; 8; 9]
Error: The function applied to this argument has type 'a list -> 'b list
This argument cannot be applied with label ~f
```

Obviously something significant changed right? Why don't these examples work? is there a better book to learn from?

This language is fantastic I would like to learn all I can but the resources are scarce.

Comment: I think the title of your question might get flagged as not descriptive :)

Comment: you just need to `open Core.Std`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using module `ListLabels` instead of `List`.

This is a question about the standard library and not the compiler, and this hasn't changed since RWO was published. RWO is using Jane Street Core, which has functions similar to `ListLabels` in the standard library. In particular, `ListLabels` and Jane Street Core `List` both have a label `f` on the function argument to `map`, whereas standard `List` does not.

[Standard ListLabels](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/ListLabels.html)

[Standard List](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html)

[Jane Street Core List](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/#Std.List)

Search in your browser for `val map` on each one of those pages to see the function signatures.

You can see that RWO is using Jane Street Core from the statement `# open Core.Std;;` at the top of RWO code. If you want to use the regular standard module `List`, do

```
List.map ((+) 3) [4;5;6];;
```

Not sure about what is going on with their online top-level.

Comment: ah I see , yes I have core installed via opam. I suppose that is the source of my problems, the wrong list function. Why are they mixing syntax between the JS core lib and the standard. They should at least show the rest of the import path. It's making reading this book very hard, there was a different example with cryptokit that they didn't even mention that required a few opens in order to compile. I wish they were more clear in their intentions. Ah well I'll keep moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out - I also had batteries opened in my file and it was getting confused between js and batteries map function. I should probably explicitly tell it when I am going to use either function. Is there an "open...as" directive in ocaml to rename my imports?

Comment: RWO seems like a good book, but I agree with you on the annoyance of using a third-party library in sections aimed at beginners. Jane Street Core incorporates some advanced techniques, so it's the easiest single library to use for later parts of the book. I think it would have been better to avoid it completely in the beginning, though. I don't think there is a good reason to use it until section II. I can't think of a good alternative off the top of my head – maybe someone else has one?

Comment: Yes, you can do `module Foo = SomeOtherModule`, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: You can also just refer to whatever you need to use without opening the module, as long as the compiler/top-level can find the file for the module. So you can not `open BatList`, but just do `BatList.map` when you want to use that.

Comment: when I do open Core.Std = ccs and try ccs.List the compiler signals an error on compile. Do you understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I think you want `module Ccs = Core.Std`. The module name has to be capitalized, and note the keyword `module` instead of `open`. Note also that the module name you are creating is on the left, because you are defining a module as an alias (the opposite of the order for "`open`...`as`").

Comment: That worked, Thanks. Any other questions I have I'll make a new question.

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing was changed. Backward compatibility is taken very seriously in the OCaml community. :)

RWO uses a library called "core". There are some differences, in particular the `f` label on `List.map`. Apparently, you don't have it loaded.

There is a guide on how to setup everything in the prelude of the book.
In the toplevel, you can do `#require "core"`.

See also [core's documentation](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/) and the [stdlib's documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Core, and other Janestreet libraries you should open the umbrella module of the library. For example, for `Core` library, a substitute for a standard library, you need to start your module with

```
open Core.Std
```

This is how library is designed. You should admit it. This operation will prepare your environment for a proper use of the library. Do not try to use any tricks, like binding `Core.Std` to other module or anything else.